# How do I make Axios show css?

Tags: javascript, css, express, axios

I am using axios to practice Web Scraping by making a Web Viewer, and I noticed that the CSS Wasn't Loading.

I used this code:

```
console.log("Tribble-Webviewer is starting!")

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const publicDir = app.use(express.static('public'))
var cheerio = require('cheerio'); // Basically jQuery for node.js
const axios = require('axios').default;
const rp = require('request-promise');
const url = 'https://pointless.com/';



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
})

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(({ data }) => res.send(data))
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Tribble-Pro is listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

If you load the /test page, the CSS does not show.

Example of the CSS not loading below:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqwRe.png)

Comment: The CSS is loaded via a relative path (`/style.css`). This means on the real website it works because the file exists. However, on your local server there is no `style.css`. So either request it separately or replace the URL in the HTML with an absolute path (`url + "style.css"`)

Comment: You could you a HTML parsing package something like `cheerio` to find the `./style.css` link tag in the document and replace the `href` attribute with ``${url}/style.css``

Comment: @GazJones My cheerio broke before this question, So I removed it. Solved it though!

Answer (score 0):

I used this async function:

```
async function getCssTest() {
 try {
  const response = await axios.get(urlplusstyle);
  res.send(response)
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
 }
}
```